# How do I to make a member variable equal another member variable which is set in main()?

Tags: c++, class, initialization, getter-setter

Consider the following C++ code for my program: [CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXc0W.png)

When I run this program, it outputs the following:

**Chocolate mass: 41

Chocolate density: nan**

I want the program to output the volume variable divided by the mass variable. It seems to be doing this correctly, but it is dividing the values initialized to the variables in the object class, rather than dividing the values assigned to the variables in the main() function. How do I fix this?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Include the code in the question, not via a link.

Comment: btw, density is mass/volume, not volume/mass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You told the software the "updated" input i.e. `weight`, `volume` and `mass` but you never told the software to update its `density` given the new values of `volume` and `mass`. The value of density is calculated once in the constructor, which is only called **once** when you created the object (not to mention that I feel pretty nervous when people do things like `0/0`). Need a separate function to update the density and **call** it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following tips will help:

1. Initialize the class members using `class constructor`s, that's why `constructors` exist.
2. Use the existing setters to update the `density`. Each time `setMass` or `setVolume` is called, recalculate the `density`.
3. Whenever you use division, make sure you don't divide by 0.
4. Initialize variable with constants of the proper type. `0` is of type `int` by default while `0.0` is of type `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok there is a bug in your program... 
Change this line:

```
Double getDensity()const{return density;}
```

To:

```
Double getDensity(){density=volume/mass;return density;}
```

And replace:

```
Double density = volume/mass;
```

To:

```
Double density;
```

Next time please paste code. Screen shots will not work...